# How to share a private Youtube live event throught the API

Tags: php, youtube-livestreaming-api

Through the API for Youtube live it is possible to create a liveBroadcast and set the status.privacyStatus property to private.

I would like to know how I can add email addresses (through the API) to the whitelist of people that can view the stream.